# Functions $ \cos(2x)$, $\sin(2ax)$, $1$ independent and dependent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For which value(s) of $a$ are the functions $\cos(2x)$, $\sin(2ax)$, $1$ independent over the real numbers? For which $a$ are they dependent?

I thought maybe to equate each (with the use of scalars), but that's a wild guess.

Comment: Do you study at Utrecht by any chance?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: set $\alpha\cos(2x)+\beta\sin(2ax)+\gamma=0$ (constant zero function) and try some values of $x$.

Further hint.

- For $x=0$ we get $\alpha+\gamma=0$
- For $x=\pi/4$ we get $\beta\sin(a\pi/2)+\gamma=0$
- For $x=\pi/2$ we get $-\alpha+\beta\sin(a\pi)+\gamma=0$

This creates a linear system with matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & \sin(a\pi/2) & 1 \\
-1 & \sin(a\pi) & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
whose determinant is
$$
2\sin(a\pi/2)-\sin(a\pi)=2\sin(a\pi/2)-2\sin(a\pi/2)\cos(a\pi/2)=
2\sin(a\pi/2)(1-\cos(a\pi/2))
$$
What can you say when this determinant is $\ne0$?

What can you do when it equals $0$?

Comment: are they then dependent over the real numbers?

Comment: @DaphneS I added another hint

Answer (score 0):

egreg's solution is correct and straight forward. I will try to present my aproach to this problem. 
If you take:$$f1=1 , f2=cos(2x) ,  f3=sin(2ax)$$
If you take $W(f1,f2,f3)$ , where W stands for Wronskian determinant. 
Which is:  $$W=\begin{pmatrix}
 f1&f2  &f3 \\ 
f1' &  f2'& f3'\\ 
 f1''&f2''  &f3'' 
\end{pmatrix} $$ 
So for $f1,f2,f3$ to be linearly independent for every $x$ must $W=0$, or to be linearly independent $W!=0$ for every $x$. I hope this helps.